# Check all IF conditions before moving forward. (Multiple If Conditions, BASH)

Tags: bash, if-statement, multiple-conditions

This is what I have. I'm forced to use a consequent command is there is a match. I want to avoid that if possible.

```
if [[ ${USER} == "user1" || "user2" || "user3" || "user4" ]]; then
     echo "user matches."
else
     echo "${USER} Does not match configured users."
     exit 1
fi
```

Is there a way to flip the syntax to exit on the subsequent command? That would look cleaner and reduce the line count. The problem here is, it will exit on the first true condition. So maybe a way to check all conditions before moving forward?

```
if [[ ${USER} != "user1" || "user2" || "user3" || "user4" ]]; then
     echo "${USER} Does not match configured users."
     exit 1
fi
```

**UPDATES BELOW**
I ended up using the following IF statement with regex. The ! changes the statement to a "does not match".

```
if ! [[ ${USER} =~ ^user1|user2|user3|user4$ ]]; then
     log "${USER} Does not match configured users."
     exit 1
fi
```

And to expand on that with using a variable:

```
USERS="user1|user2|user3|user4"

if ! [[ ${USER} =~ ^${USERS}$ ]]; then
     log "${USER} Does not match configured users."
     exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

I Don't think the If statement is doing what you think it is;

for example

```
 $ if [[ "a" == "b" || "c" ]] ; then echo y; else echo n; fi
 y
```

since ("a"=="b") is false, but "c" without condition is true
and hence `false || true` is `true`
but, im pretty sure that you expected it to be false "n"

instead use a case statement like this;

```
case "${USER}" in
 "user1" | "user2" | "user3" | "user4")
     echo "user matches."
     ;;
 *)
     echo "${USER} Does not match configured users."
     exit 1 ;;
esac
```

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. In my first example, if any of the conditions match. I'm expecting a "true"; which is working correctly.

On the second example, I'm looking for a way to make the statement true if the conditions do not match. The problem was, it would show as true as soon as the first condition doesn't match, without checking the others.

Cool case statement. I never thought of using it for this.

Answer (score -1):

Flip the syntax, if I understood correctly your question, you can do by negating it the condition that you wanna "flip" by using the "!" operator.

Example:

```
if ! [[ ${USER} == "user1" || "user2" || "user3" || "user4" ]]; then
```

But it could be done by the connective AND, in bash represented by "&&".

Ex.:

```
if [[ ${USER} != "user1" && "user2" && "user3" && "user4" ]]; then
```

Comment: I agree that Boolean logic normally works as what you describe -- Did you test this?

Comment: This was pretty much what I'm trying to accomplish. If all conditions do not match = true. But if only one condition does match, it will = false. Just curious, is boolean logic not recommended for this?